# Libgdx EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)

Tags: java, libgdx, jvm

I'm currently trying to learn libGdx by following tutorial from a book titled "Learning Libgdx Game Development" and found a strange bug.

There is a function called backToMenu :

```
private void backToMenu () {
    // switch to menu screen
    game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game));
}
```

Its purpose is simply change the game screen ito main menu screen. The game start on the MenuScreen which transition to GameScreen, initiated by user click. Once the user is on the GameScreen, he/she have two ways to come back into MainMenu, either by hitting escape button or when game over state is reached. First, by hit the escape button, I simply listen for the event :

```
public boolean keyUp (int keycode) {
    // Back to Menu
    if (keycode == Input.Keys.ESCAPE)
        backToMenu();

    return false;
}
```

The keyUp is an overriden InputAdapter function. This one works perfectly fine. The problem occurs on the second option :

```
public void update (float deltaTime)
{
    handleDebugInput(deltaTime);
    if (isGameOver()) {
        timeLeftGameOverDelay -= deltaTime;
        if (timeLeftGameOverDelay < 0)
        {
            //init();
            backToMenu();
        }
    }
```

The code simply means, after "Game Over" message is displayed for 3 seconds, user will automatically redirected into main menu. The update function is called each time render function of the main game loop is called. But after the user comes back to main menu and tried to re enter into Game Screen, I got the following error :

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

```
     EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x77015d8b, pid=6184, tid=5856
    JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_91-b15) (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
    Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.91-b15 mixed mode windows-x86 )
    Problematic frame:
     C  [ntdll.dll+0x55d8b]
```

Strangely, if I tried to simulate user pressing escape button instead of directly calling backToMenu, it suddenly works! The user can go back and forth between MainScreen -> GameScreen -> GameOver -> MainScreen -> GameScreen just fine

```
public void update (float deltaTime)
{
    handleDebugInput(deltaTime);
    if (isGameOver()) {
        timeLeftGameOverDelay -= deltaTime;
        if (timeLeftGameOverDelay < 0)
        {
            //init();
            try {
                Robot robot = new Robot();
                // Simulate a key press
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, I don't know what the exact problem is so workaround is to generate the key event of ESCAPE Key
But you can do it more efficiently without robot by replacing

```
try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            // Simulate a key press
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

With`keyUp(Keys.ESCAPE);`